# Python 3.2 PyRun_SimpleString - Where is it?

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I am trying to ship an app together with a customised distribution of Python (has added modules and my own extensions).

To keep it simple and not risk conflicts with potential existing installations, I thought the best way would be to ship the .\DLLS*.* and .\Lib*.* trees from \Python32\ with my app under a subdirectory .\MyApp\Python\

I only directly call 3 Py* functions:
(code is C++ Builder...)

```
typedef void (__stdcall *PY_SETPYTHONHOME) (wchar_t *);
PY_SETPYTHONHOME Py_SetPythonHome;

typedef void (__stdcall *PY_INITIALIZE) ();
PY_INITIALIZE Py_Initialize;

typedef int (__stdcall *PYRUN_SIMPLESTRING) (const char *);
PYRUN_SIMPLESTRING PyRun_SimpleString;




HMODULE py_dll_hndle;
py_dll_hndle = ::LoadLibrary((ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName) + "Python\\DLLS\\python3.dll").c_str());
ShowMessage(py_dll_hndle == NULL ? L"Bah" : L"Yay");     // Result: "Yay"


Py_SetPythonHome = (PY_SETPYTHONHOME) ::GetProcAddress(py_dll_hndle, "Py_SetPythonHome");
ShowMessage(Py_SetPythonHome == NULL ? L"Bah" : L"Yay");     // Result: "Yay"


Py_Initialize = (PY_INITIALIZE) ::GetProcAddress(py_dll_hndle, "Py_Initialize");
ShowMessage(Py_Initialize == NULL ? L"Bah" : L"Yay");     // Result: "Yay"


PyRun_SimpleString = (PYRUN_SIMPLESTRING) ::GetProcAddress(py_dll_hndle, "PyRun_SimpleString");
ShowMessage(GetLastError());     // Result: "127" (ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND)
ShowMessage(PyRun_SimpleString == NULL ? L"Bah" : L"Yay");     // Result: "Bah"
```

PyRun_SimpleString doesn't exist? I've looked for using http://www.nirsoft.net/ DLL export viewer... It's not there. I'm confused... Where the 'ell is it?

Comment: Documentation indicates this function still exists: http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_SimpleString

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it exists, I've called it. I used to use an import lib, but decided to change to manually loading the DLL. I thought it would be simple... Ha!

Comment: Try importing `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(const char *command, PyCompilerFlags *flags)` (and passing `NULL` for `flags`) and creating your own `PyRun_SimpleString` wrapper function.

Comment: If you run a DLL explorer programme on python3.dll there is *no* PyRun_ anything...  So the gist of my question is, if it isn't in python3.dll, then where is it?

Answer (score 5):

There are two DLL's python3.dll and python32.dll. The first is a subset of the second. There is only one copy of python32.dll - hidden away in my \Windows\SysWOW64\ directory, while python3.dll was in the c:\Python32\DLLs directory as well.

Using python32.dll instead of python3.dll solved the issue.

Remains a mystery why there is a partial duplication though...

Comment: You may mark this answer as the solution to your question, by the way!

Comment: @user1373893 to answer the differences between python3.dll and python310.dll,  python3.dll contains only the methods in the stable ABI (as suggested by the generic "3" in the name, which is why the ``PyRun_SimpleString`` is not present), while the other contains all symbols.